# How many instructions execute for a O(1) operation on a list with n elements?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

a. always one
b. no more than n
c. some fixed number
d. no more than 3

I chose "no more than n", but my teacher told me that it is wrong. She didn't give the reason why it was wrong, and if it is wrong then what is the answer to it?

Comment: b was the easiest answer to eliminate as possible candidate answer. This would mean that an operation on an empty list (let say ask it for its size) would execute in no more then 0 instructions ... which is of course impossible

Comment: @Robin that assumes that 'ask it for its size' is an O(1) operation.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst correct. But it does not really matter which method it is. Something that executes in no more then 0 steps simply can't do anything

Comment: @Robin something that executes in no more than 0 steps (i.e. exactly zero steps) can not do anything useful or interesting (or harmful either) but is nonetheless O(1) - but apparently not Θ(1).

Answer (score 7):

The answer is none of them.  The method below is O(1).

1. Clearly it is not always one.
2. It is sometimes more than n.
3. Clearly it is not a fixed number.
4. It is always more than three.

//

```
public void run ( List of size n )
{
     for ( int i = 0 ; i < 100 + ( n  % 100 ) ; i ++ )
     {
          step ( ) ;
     }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer; note that this is not Θ(1) (does not run in constant time / fixed number), but its *upper limit* is a fixed number - in this case 199 iterations.

Comment: This is a great counterexample.  It might be nice to note that (C) is intended as the correct answer, and explain why, even though there are some exceptions.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst, The upper limit is a constant number of operations and the lower limit is a constant number of operations, ergo the algorithm is Θ(1).  It happens that the two constants are not the same, but that is not required by the definition of Θ(1): f(n) = Θ(g(n)) if g(n) * k1 <= f(n) <= g(n) * k2 for some positive k1 and k2. (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Comment: @DanielStutzbach Thnx for the links to definitions.  If I understand correctly, if I just change the method so that the lower limit is zero (e.g., `i < n % 100`) then it would no longer be Θ(1).  (k1 and k2 both have to be positive.)  I don't really understand why k1 can't be zero.

Comment: @emory: That's an interesting point that I had not considered before.  For the Ω(n) portion, if you permitted k to be zero, then f(n) >= g(n) * k would be true for any f(n) and g(n) by selecting k to be zero.  That would not be a very useful definition. ;)

Comment: @emory: Except your method would still be Ω(1), since you always run the comparison, which takes non-zero time (or whatever unit you use). I am pretty sure the reason k1 can't be zero is because a Ω(0) would have to be Θ(0), since you wouldn't be able to even perform a check. By extension there is only one such method (NOP), so talking about Θ(0) is pointless.

Answer (score 5):

The right answer is c. some fixed number.
The idea is that the operation always takes the same time regardless of the number of elements.
[See constant time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_time#Constant_time)

Comment: Hrrrrrm.  _O(1)_ implies that the operation _at most_ some constant time, which only means that there's a constant upper bound -- it's not necessarily always exactly the same number of operations.  I'd say that none of these are quite accurate, but heck, d) comes closer to the spirit of things.

Comment: Agree with Louis - "*at most* some constant time". See @emory answer below for a nice example of an O(1) that doesn't have constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Some fixed number.

`O(1)` means constant time or it means that the time to execute doesn't depend on the size of the input (even though it may take longer than the end of the universe to execute).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10097498/348975 for an example of an O(1) function that the time to execute does depend on the size of the input.

Answer (score 0):

Some fixed number would be the correct answer. You can have a function do n-1 or n+1 operations and b)/d) would be satisfied, but would still be in O(n) time. O(1) time requires that there is a fixed number C such that the function runs in C operations, regardless of n.

There should be an algorithms tag instead of a Java tag too :P